# How to Add Text Dynamically in Head Section in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add the server name in my page head section dynamically like

```
<head>
<!-- DP2-WEB005 -->
</head>
```

can anyone please let me know how can I add this `<!-- DP2-WEB005 -->` tag in head section.

server name I will handle it but I don't know how add that commented tag dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HtmlGenericControl newControl = new HtmlGenericControl("someTag");
newControl.Attributes["someAttr"] = "some value";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(newControl);
```

I hope this helps ... 
([the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982099/asp-net-dynamically-insert-code-into-head))

**UPDATE:**

This is that you want :

```
string serverName = "QWERTY123";
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<!-- " + serverName + "-->"));
```

And here is the output :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><!-- QWERTY123--></head>
```

Comment: Thanks dude I have already tried it but I want commented tag while in this case it will create a server tag in page

Answer (score 2):

```
<head runat="server">
<%= serverName %>
</head>
```

In code behind

```
public string serverName{get;set;}

protected void Page_Load(object o, EventArgs e)
{
 serverName="assign";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**Aspx:**

```
   <html>
    <head runat="server">
      <%= Content %>
    </head>
    <body>
      //Code here
    </body>
   </html>
```

**Code Behind:**

In Code behind write the following code in PageLoad()

```
public string Content{get;set;}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  String Content = "Content here";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want in commented tag as mentioned in question

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me to the right direction. The only thing is that "String Content" didn´t work for me. Just:  Content = "Content herer";  did work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `css` or java-script in your page section you can use the following

```
 var myHtmlLink = new HtmlLink { Href = @"filepath" };
 myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
 myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
 Page.Header.Controls.AddAt("0", myHtmlLink);
```